# How to determine delta between common columns and rows in two data frames

Tags: r

I am looking for a way to create a data frame that is the result of subtracting two data frames of unequal number of columns and rows.

I created the following example of two data frames:

```
R> t1
Link, P1, P2, P3 
A,  1,  4,  7
B,  2,  5,  8
C,  3,  6,  9

R> t2
Link, P1, P3, P5
A,  1,  5,  1
C,  2,  6,  3
D,  3,  7,  5
F,  4,  8,  7
```

The resulting data frame needs to represent the difference between common columns and rows:

```
R> intersect(names(t1),names(t2))
[1] "Link" "P1"   "P3"  
R> intersect(t1$Link,t2$Link)
[1] "A" "C"
R> t1 - t2
Link, P1, P3
A, 0, 2
C, 1, 3
```

I do have many columns/rows in the two data frames. I tried several options with the merge with no luck. I'm looking for ideas on how to proceed.

Comment: The example tables are created using the following: t1 <- data.frame(Link=c('A','B','C'),P1=c(1,2,3),P2=c(4,5,6),P3=c(7,8,9)) and t2 <- data.frame(Link=c('A','C','D','F'),P1=c(1,2,3,4),P3=c(5,6,7,8),P5=c(1,3,5,7))

Comment: you want the intersection or the difference? you are almost there in the first case.

Comment: It's not clear to me how you wish to 'subtract two data frames.' I think if you simply clarify what you wish to do, the answer will be obvious to you.

Comment: I believe OP wants to do an inner join based on the `Link` column, and then look at the row-wise differences for any other columns that share the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution:

```
rownames(t1)<-t1$Link
rownames(t2)<-t2$Link
col_intersect<-intersect(names(t1),names(t2))
row_intersect<-intersect(t1$Link,t2$Link)
t1[row_intersect,col_intersect[-1]] - t2[row_intersect,col_intersect[-1]]
```

Output:

```
  P1 P3
A  0  2
C  1  3
```

To answer your comment; assuming device_nr is consistent in t1 and t2

```
result<-t1[row_intersect,col_intersect[-1]] - t2[row_intersect,col_intersect[-1]]
result[,"device_nr"]<-t1[rownames(result),"device_nr"]
```

Output:

```
  device_nr P1 P3
A        45  0  2
C        67  1  3
```

Comment: Thanks. Works perfect.

Comment: What if I have an additional column in both data frames that I would like to carry over to the delta data frame. e.g.
t1 <- data.frame(Link=c('A','B','C'),device_nr=c(45,56,67),P1=c(1,2,3),P2=c(4,5,6),P3=c(7,8,9))

t2 <- data.frame(Link=c('A','C','D','F'),device_nr=c(45,67,78,90),P1=c(1,2,3,4),P3=c(5,6,7,8),P5=c(1,3,5,7))

How can I keep the device_nr?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's a dplyr solution. Pivot to long, aggregate using `diff` then cast back to wide:

```
require(dplyr)
require(reshape2)
require(magrittr)

local({
    t1$df <- "t1"
    t2$df <- "t2"    
    n <- intersect(names(t1), names(t2))
    rbind(t1[n], t2[n])
}) %>% 
melt(id.vars=c("Link", "df")) %>% 
arrange(Link, variable, desc(df)) %>%
group_by(Link, variable) %>% 
filter(length(value) == 2) %>% 
summarise(delta = diff(value)) %>% 
dcast(Link~variable)
```